# How PDF viewer works on Android

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I went through the open source of pdf viewer in android.

My guess is that they convert the pdf pages in to images. Google by default does not any library functions to parse or display a pdf. Is there any way to render pdf instead of displaying them as image?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be easier to use a library. So far I've used http://itextpdf.com/ and it works well... On Java in an App Server :P . Using it with Android should be interesting.

Comment: I have tried it only generates but i doubt it cant be used for displaying existing pdf

Comment: Googling it says http://pdfbox.apache.org/ can be used to read the documents. However you should present it in some way. Apparently the easiest approach is to create an image and that's why most apps use it. If needed you can create it manually in a view, though. But I don't think it'll be easy at all.